# Java String to Byte. Why does the value get changed?

Tags: java

I have the following method, where I am setting the value "9" in String. When I put this in byte and display the output then the value gets changed.

```
void method() {
    String s = "9";
    byte[] b = s.getBytes();
    System.out.println("Byte value is: " + byte[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Byte value is: 57
```

Here why is 9 getting converted to 57?

Comment: Because `String.getBytes()` does not do what you think it does. Read [the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()).

Comment: Because the character `'9'` is 57.

Answer (score 3):

Because the character `'9'` is ASCII value 57:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

ASCII character 9 would be a "tab" character

Comment: I want to get a number from user, which is always between 0 to 9. I want to store the user's input in byte variable rather than short or int. I want to further use this input in IF statement later in the code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to store in a byte?

Comment: Use the `parseByte` method of the `Byte` class.

Answer (score 2):

57 is the ASCII code for the character '9'

Answer (score 0):

when you trying to get byte value from character you get only ASCII value.

character '9' ASCII code is 57

Answer (score 0):

In above example you need to correct the compilation problems first:
It should code should be like :

```
 System.out.println("Byte value is: " + b[0]);
```

And not

```
 System.out.println("Byte value is: " + byte[0];
```

And regarding the output, You are assigning "9" as string and trying to fetch the byte[], basically getBytes encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array. hence your getting "57".

Comment: Thanks!

Actually my code is OK. Its a typo while posting :)